# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Node Version Conflict

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'll keep it short and simple. We're currently running an ElasticBeanstalk setup with Amazon Linux v2.0.6. This version supports 4.x NodeJS, and 0.12.9 NodeJS. Unfortunately, due to a critical fix that was introduced after 0.12.9, I need to upgrade my node version, but stay on 0.12.x. For those of you who know ELB, it version locks Node to a few specific versions... and it seems that I'm stuck with either my current version of Node, which is unacceptable, or upgrading to the latest Amazon Linux (v4.1.0) which drops support for 0.12.x.

We're going to move past 0.12.x soon, but it's not an option yet. So what are my current choices? Is there a way I'm not seeing to manually select an old Amazon Linux version? If not, is there a way to manually build Node v0.12.18 on my instances and have them default to using that? Or, is there a way to introduce the patch to the current binaries, which would appear to ELB as the same Node version? The change is literally 2 lines of code, but it's absolutely crucial.

Cheers for your help - let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

0.12 is EOL. 4.x will be EOL in less than a year. Are you 100% certain you can't move to 4, or even better, 8?

End mandatory version-shaming.

You probably need to use a custom Beanstalk template, that uses an AMI with the Linux and Node versions you need.

Seriously, 8.x is like a new language. It's so nice.